# WordPress options table

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a form with two input fields and a submit button on my custom admin menu page.

Now I want to save the inserted data in the input fields into the WordPress options table on submit button click

not got any solution till now.

Comment: Read the `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables, sanitize them, put them in an array and do `update_option`.

Comment: Which of these steps do you need help with? And what did you try?

Comment: i need help with the $_POST  method.

Comment: here  below is my form .... please guide how i can send the data that would be inserted into these input fields to the wp_options table 
    <form  method = "post"  action = "options.php">
     <input type = "text " name = "Option1" value = ""/>
     <br><br>
 <input type = "text "  name = "Option2" value = ""/> 
     <br><br>
  <input type = "submit" name="send_option" value = "Save Changes"/>
</form>

Comment: I'm very beginner to wordpress and php

Comment: You can get the variables using `$_POST['Option1']` and `$_POST['Option2']`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Klaassiek for helping me out.

Comment: There is a bit more to do when developing a settings page on WordPress's dashboard backend. Please read this example. https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/custom-settings-page/  There is some learning in your near future.